# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in production environment

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have an ASP.NET core website that I'm building and something weird is happening when I deploy the app on my server. While debugging everything works fine (Dev env) but when I run the app through a Docker container in production mode, it refuses to let users log in and I'm getting

`Uncaught ReferenceError: JQueryError: Jquery is not defined`

There are absolutely no errors in the source code.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your _Layout.cshtml and _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml files. You should have something like this in those files:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</environment>

<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js" (...)></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" (...)></script>
</environment>
```

Make sure you have proper paths to your jQuery in Developer and Production Environment - jquery.js, jquery.min.js, jquery.validate.js and so on. Use Network tab in Developers Tools in Chrome to check exactly which file is missing.